# useQuery doesn't return the data and the function is returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-query

I'm trying to get the list of the chats in my app using react-query(useQuery). my API call is in a different component and I'm using Axios to get the data. but the component is returning the function itself not the data .which part is Wrong?

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const getContacts = async () => {
  const headers = { Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token") };
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/mine/",
    headers: headers,
  };
  const { data } = await axios.request(options);

  return data;
};
function GetUserDataUseQuery() {
  return useQuery("getContacts", getContacts);
}
export default GetUserDataUseQuery;

function getUserData() {
  const data = GetUserDataUseQuery;

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CONTACTS,
      payload: [],
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused what the `getUserData` function is supposed to do, also, `const data = GetUserDataUseQuery;` should be `const data = useUserData()` (change to lower case and rename for best practice)` since that's a hook

Comment: "Which part is wrong?" well, for starters, that's an illegal hook call, hooks can only be called from function components or other hooks. Second, your `getUserData` returns a function, and I don't see any components, so what's your question?

Comment: `getUserData` function has been used in a component and actually dispatches the values to reducer .and I didn't use `useUserData` because `getUserData` is not in a component.I've used this type of code for `useMutation` and it worked  correctly

Comment: the component is in speared place and it calls the `getUserData` on loading .`getUserData` is actually an action to dispatch data to reducer

Comment: You'll need to refactor your code to properly handle your use case then - whatever you have right now above is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you refactor your code a little to fix some of your problems:

```js
const getContacts = async () => { /*...*/ }
const useGetContacts = () => {
  return useQuery('getContacts', getContacts)
}

// `useGetContacts` is a hook, so it should be called inside of a 
// component or another hook - you *cannot* call a hook inside of a 
// simple function, which is what you're attempting to do inside `getUserData`

function MyComponent() {
  const contacts = useGetContacts();
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you do want to use `getContacts` as if it was a function, then simply don't wrap it inside a `useQuery`, since that's what turns it into a hook.

```js
async function getUserData() {
  const data = await getContacts()
  // ...
}
```

Comment: the `getUserData()` is an action and has been called inside a component to get the data, I've used `useMutation` in exact way and it works very good

Comment: I don't have context of how you've used `useMutation` before, so I can't comment on that, but given your original code, you can **only** use hooks inside function components and/or custom hooks - see [Breaking the Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks).

Comment: I found out what to do based on your suggestion.thank you